# SQL 2014 - login problems using TCP/IP

Tags: sql-server, named-pipes, tcp

I have an MS Access database which was developed on a Windows 10 client, with a local instance of SQL Server, using Access 2016. I'm now in the process of deploying it on a client's network, which uses Win 7 clients, and SQL 2014 on MS Small Business server. We are using Windows Authentication. I have no control over any of these elements.

All works absolutely fine on my machine.

On the client's network, when the database application tries to connect, I get a long delay, followed by "Unable to complete login process due to delay in opening server connection". I've tried various different drivers, including ODBC driver 13 for SQL Server, SNAC 11 and the built-in SQL Server driver. All experience exactly the same issue. I've tried specifying an IP address rather than the server name as part of the connection string, but that made no difference for the better or worse.

However, when I get the dialog box with the above error, I click "OK" and am then prompted with another SQL Login box. I click OK again, and the application connects instantly, with no further errors, and thereafter works fine.

I've spent all morning trying to isolate and fix this issue. Finally, I tried disabling the TCP/IP protocol on the server, and leaving Named Pipes as the only option. Suddenly, all works like a dream - no delays, instant login, great performance.

I would leave it at that, except that all the reading I've done indicates that the busier a network, the worse Named Pipes will perform, and I'm conscious that at this stage there are only a couple of us testing whereas when we go live, there'll be lots more people doing quite demanding work with the DB.

So, does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing the connection issues I'm seeing when using TCP/IP? Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks a lot.
Andrew

Comment: Very likely there is a problem with a firewall blocking the SQL Server ports. Named pipes go over port 445 over SMB, that's open by default in Windows, while port 1433 is blocked by default.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply Alejandro. I wondered about that (and I'm not an expert on firewalls!) but wouldn't that mean that I just couldn't connect using TCP/IP? Whereas what's actually happening is that I can't connect, get an error, then try again. The first attempt fails every time, the second succeeds.

Or would that be TCP/IP failing, then rolling over to Named Pipes as an alternative and succeeding?

Comment: What happens after the second SQL login appears? You said it works after that, but does it keep working even if you close it and open it again? If you restart the computer? Or is a "one time" pseudo solution? I think that dialog switches to named pipes, and TCP/IP never worked really. Note that on your machine there is also a third possibility, shared memory, only possible within the same computer.

Comment: To answer your last question, it was only fixing it for that session - so everything fine until you log off, then next time, we're back to the same 1 min wait, second dialog box, then all good again.

However, good news - I've now managed to fix it, thanks to your original suggestion. The issue was indeed the firewall. Having opened the firewall for SQL Server, and it's now working well - instant logins, and no problems. So, thanks for your help - much appreciated.